# Removing or replacing findbugs, PMD, checkStyle plugins android

Tags: java, android, plugins

I'm using a clone of an app which uses FindBugs, PMD, CheckStyle plugins.
But now, i've made some changes which makes minimum Gradle version to 6.5 and now i'm getting this error:

> Plugin with id 'findbugs' not found.

As i read, the findbugs is deprecated for gradle 5.0+ .

Now, how can i remove the usage of these 3 plugins in this clone? Or how can i replace it(i think SpotBugs is the new version of it!)
Or how to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Findbugs and Add Spotbugs in your project.

You don't need to remove PMD and CheckStyle. They are working perfectly.

Only change is of Findbugs.